# Firebase Function onCreate does not work

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I want to send an email when a new order is created in my firebase database, but nothing happens when I create an order. My function:

```
    exports.sendEmailConfirmation = functions.database.ref('/orders').onCreate(event => { 

  const mailOptions = {
    from: '"Someone." <noreply@firebase.com>',
    to: 'someone@gmail.com',
  };

  // Building Email message.
  mailOptions.subject = 'New order from mobile app!';
  mailOptions.text = 'John Doe lorem ipsum';

  return mailTransport.sendMail(mailOptions)
    .then(() => console.log('¡¡¡ Enail sent !!!'))
    .catch((error) => console.error('Error!!', error));
});
```

This code works using onWrite()....

Answer (score 7):

Your function isn't triggering because `/orders` already exists.  onCreate triggers will only run when the path you specify is newly created.

If you want to know when a child is newly added under `/orders`, you should use a wildcard in the path:

```
functions.database.ref('/orders/{orderId}')
```

Comment: orderId must exists in my database?

Comment: Just came across this. orderId is the wid card Dough is referring to. When you create an order inside the order, this function triggers and the orderId will hold the id of the newly created order.

Comment: The actual name "orderId" here is made up yeh or at least does not refer to a specific term?